# What kind of methods can one use to bind two objects as one, without any adhesive

Tags: material-selection, plastic, sculpting

I'm thinking of methods, similar to how some products use a lid to snap onto an object so that it remains clipped to that particular object and snaps into place. However, I want no 3rd party material applications used. Just mechanisms used to combine two objects temporarily into place to become as one structure.

I'm sorry if this doesn't exactly paint the perfect picture in your head and also if didn't use proper terminology to properly describe what I am looking for.. However, any help, lead or point towards a direction to find this would be helpful, even it isn't the whole answer.

Again thank you for your time.

Comment: What are the objects you want to hold together? I think the answer will be specific to that. For instance, if they have edges that stick out, you might be able to use a small clamp, but that might not work on other objects. Could you provide a picture of the sort of lids you mean?

Comment: This sounds like you are looking for help with an invention - but without sayng what you are trying to do, for what purpose, and with what materials, it's pretty hard to answer.  Maybe a patent search whould tell you what's out there now.

Comment: Welcome to A&C! As whrrgarbl and abbie noted, we really need you to be more specific. Right now, you're asking for a potentially endless list of ideas. Anything you can add to this would be helpful to us. Until then, I'm putting this question on hold. Feel free to [edit] your additional information in and flag it for moderator attention. Thanks!

Comment: Check this out (Similar to a puzzle piece) for 2D https://goo.gl/photos/8sZ1PDJTUWZkEgaK6

Comment: For 3D check this out https://goo.gl/photos/U1LYrByvMP6ffHeT6

Comment: Similar to what is used in zip lock bags

Comment: Thank you everyone for your contributions. Sorry for delay as everything is tough to balance that is going on around me and in this digital age where everything is in a swift response. 

I am looking to create a mechanism to solve a problem for an object I am looking to innovate.. so I wanted to use this post to see if any of my world citizen peers can help me clarify what I want to be able to achieve. 

Given that English is my 3rd language, it is tough for me to use the terminology for such a thing, to enable me to better research the subject.So I thank you. 

@abbie you are correct.

Comment: The material can be plastic of any kind or anything that is similar to plastic, but that would be the second phase as now I am looking to design it as I am researching for possible mechanisms.

@catija you are correct, this is what i am looking for, possible ideas that can possibly fit into the design i want, however, with my poor acknowledgement of English terminologies for such mechanisms, it is becoming difficult to research. But as the gentleman below, fastener and assembly are good starts for the cause.

Comment: Moreover, the basic function of this object is composed of two objects being adjacent to each other that open and close but I want to make it where at a certain position, with one hand, flick of a finger or button pressed, they can remain closed or open. 

So in a sense for example: If I open this switch, the two objects collapse, and then when I reverse the process, I can keep it in open position upon closing the switch or some form of a mechanism that enables them to remain in that open position.. hope this can clarify the picture better with my words without the drawings to demonstrate it

Comment: AGAIN THANK YOU FOR YOUR CONTRIBUTIONS 

:D

Answer (score 2):

A general term you may find helpful here is *fastening*.

A search on *fastening method* turns up some interesting resources that discuss various fastening methods used in industry. I'd start there with the abstract discussions. Those are likely places to find other general category terms you can use to refine your search.

I found this one interesting for a start: [Fastening & Assembly](https://www.sme.org/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=73743).

It would indicate what you're looking for may belong to the category "integral fasteners".

Comment: Thank you, this terminology is helpful in narrowing down what I want to achieve.  

If there are any other words , I am open to hearing you for more info.

Comment: Also, figured out that a Latch for hardware is another technique